# Read text from Sharepoint WebPart [c#]

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I want to read text form my webpart. Its a simple one: just a line of text - nothing else.
I can get properties of my webparts (like title, desc etc) but can't get the content of it. Any ideas how to retreive this information? Thanks in advance.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysite/pwa/some_web"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPFile file = web.GetFile("default.aspx"); 
                using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
                {
                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.WebPart wp in wpm.WebParts)
                    {                            
                        Console.WriteLine("Web part: {0}", wp.Title);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think, because the html will get generated only when the webpart is loaded into a webpart manager and is shown on a site, you will have a bad time...

Why don't you change the webpart, when its "your's"?

Comment: It is webpart which generate some data and I want to use it in another one. Dont have its code.

Comment: You could try to find it's assembly on the server and look for some kind of API...

Answer (score 0):

`WebPart` is the base class where other web part classes inherit from, and only contains the common properties such as `Title`. To read a specific property, you need to cast that `wp` object to the actual class of the web part.

Within the foreach loop:

```
MyWebPartClass mwp = (MyWebPartClass)wp;
Console.WriteLine(wp.SomeProperty);
```

Where `MyWebPartClass` inherits `WebPart` and declares the property `SomeProperty`. Note that you should also check first that the `wp` object is in fact a webpart of your class, in case there are more web parts on the same page